# What is the best way for Incremental Load in SSIS

Tags: ssis, increment

I am trying to create an incremental load from Source table into `mrr/src` tables, and in my Source table I've got `created` date and '`modified`' date.

Adding New Records:

There are two approaches to do the incremental, and I am wondering which way is better:

1. Merge join task (left join) between Source table and mrr/src table and taking all records which are not exist in mrr/src table.
2. saving the last upload date and taking all new records, which have higher 'created' date than the last upload date.

I personally choose the second option, but is the first option is more preferable in terms of performance ?

Updating existing Records:

Again there are two options:

1. Using Conditional Split task and having all comparisons between fields in Source Table and mrr/src table.
2. Using 'Modified' date in Source table and compare it to last upload date,
   in order to know which records were updated since the last time i checked the Source table.

Is there a preferred option, and am I missing an option?

Comment: Way too many variables and possibilities here to give you an answer that will actually be relevant to your situation.  Do some research, do your testing and find what works best for you.

Comment: option 1 is my preferred choice because it will 100% ensure you take all modified records (even when the 'modidfied' field isn't modified but others are). performance wise option 1 is slower in general. (you need to match all columns instead of just one)

Comment: Option 2 is a tried and tested approach but it is a little more complex. Regardless, if you want efficient ETL processes you should understand that joins, lookups. etc. in SSIS are slow, where loading into staging tables and running SQL on the staging data is fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding New Records:
I prefer #2 (assuming that the created date will be always higher that the last insert date). Also option #2 is better for those cases that the source table will grow up greatly. 
It will perform fast overt time contrary to option #1 that the bigger the table the more time it will take to compare all the data.

Updating existing Records:
Option #2 but again this is assuming that the modification date will ALWAYS change when a field is changed. 
Tip for faster update performance. Instead of updating the records on the fly. Just save the records in a temporary physical table and with another step in the SSIS package issue a SQL Script to use that temporary table as a reference to update the main final table. This is way faster than using the SQL Task on the dataflow. This task will issue an update statement per each row.

Comment: thanks a lot for the elaboration
it gave me confidence with what i did.

regarding the suggestion for the Updating existing Records,
this is exactly how i did it, it helps in also monitoring the updated records.